# CSS3-how do I set to distance between two areas same in all screen sizes

Tags: css

I have ad (on left - banner) and content sections. As the screen size increases, the distance between these two areas are increasing too. How can I fix that ? how can I set to distance between two areas same in all screen sizes ?

I'm trying @media queries like below;

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) { 
.leftbanner {
 padding-left: 15px;
}} 
@media only screen and (max-width:1366px) { 
.leftbanner {
 padding-left: 85px;
}}
```

But its required to set for all screen sizes and not working as I expected.. Is there an easier way to do what I say?

Comment: Just specify it outside the media query. In that way it will be applied for all the screen sizes.

Comment: I edited question, padding varies in every sizes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cervantes Basically I think that there is some CSS other than what you have pasted in your question that is causing the padding to vary with screen size.

You could try overriding the padding outside the media queries as suggested before to see if this is true.

Something like this:

```
.leftbanner {
 padding-left: 15px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) { 
.leftbanner {
 /*padding-left: 15px;*/
}} 
@media only screen and (max-width:1366px) { 
.leftbanner {
 /*padding-left: 85px;*/
}}
```

you can even add an !important like this

```
 .leftbanner {
     padding-left: 15px !important;
 }
```

to force it to override just for the purpose of debugging. If "important" works it means that there should be some other CSS that is changing your padding.

Answer (score 0):

Just define that setting *outside* (i.e. above or below) all media queries and erase it from the media queries.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it with codes, I'm newbie in css. Mostly I'm dealing with php-javascript

Comment: Now I don't understand what you want - you had the same setting in both media queries in your original question (?). It seems you are talking about settings that you didn't even post in your question.

Comment: original question was wrong :/ media queries had same padding value. But I edited it

Answer (score 0):

hmm you mean position it relatively to the viewport? you need to forget about media queries and just use viewport units then. Something like

```
.leftbanner{padding-left: 5vw;}
```